# Сериализация объектов в python на примере datetime.datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, сериализация, десериализация

Каким образом решить проблему:

```
{TypeError}Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

Важно оставить объект `datetime.datetime`, так как у него реализован оператор сравнения

Comment: pickle.........

Comment: И что мне потом с ним делать? Мне json нужен. Кроме того pickle -- черепаха/

Comment: черепаха — "это нас не касается", а делать так: `import pickle;dt=pickle.dumps(your_datetime);# а теперь dt добавляем в json`, достать так: `pickle.loads(dt_serialized)`. Костыль конечно...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно с `datetime.datetime` помог такой рецепт:

```
json.dumps(my_dictionary, default=str)
```

который я взял из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable) ответа на вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Сериализуй в строку в iso  формат по гринвичу. Сравнение строк даст тот же результат.

Также можно сериализовать в таймштамп unix. Но строку легче отличить при работе с сериализаторами.

[Как написать сериализатор](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Кроме json и pickle есть ещё много форматов, например, [msgpack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#timestamp-extension-type)